# Center Center align in Internet Explorer is offset

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am new to [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and having some trouble getting a loading bar `div` to be centered horizontally and vertically within Internet Explorer (works fine in Chrome/FF).

I have already perused through the known flexbox issues and cannot seem to pinpoint this one's fix.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/suunyz3e/223/

**HTML**

```
<main ng-app="sandbox" flex layout="column" class="col-xs-12" id="view">

  <md-content class="loader" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex>
    <div id="title" flex>
      <span>Loading...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress" flex>
      <div flex class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-content>

</main>
```

**CSS**

```
#view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  max-width: 260px;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  margin-top: -72px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**Image**

[image]

My goal is to do most, if not all, of my layout using just material design elements - so I would be interested in advice if I am using it wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has probles with centering the element if parent is `layout="row"`.

EDIT_01: It has problems if there is only one element centered vertically or something like that, I had the same issues with that.

If you want both "title" and "progress" to be centered like in jsfiddle, you should use `layout="column"` for "loader" and no absolute positioning for "title":

**HTML**

```
<main ng-app="sandbox" flex layout="column" class="col-xs-12" id="view">

  <md-content class="loader" layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex>
    <div id="title">
      <span>Loading...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-content>

</main>
```

**CSS**

```
#view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;          -- to stretch it to 260px max
  max-width: 260px;
}

#title {
  color: black;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

EDIT_02: Also there were many redundant `flex` attributes.

EDIT_03: Using `layout-fill`argument will save some work, you don't need to flex to many elements and use to manny layout settings: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/224/

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, in your HTML, the second layout is typed `collumn` (took me a minute to realize why it wasn't aligning correctly) haha

Comment: Sorry :D My bad. Also using `layout-fill` is good to use: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/suunyz3e/223/). You don't need to set layout and flex it that much and set 100% height and width with this.

Comment: Thanks! Quick side Q (if you have a moment), how would I achieve 4 equal quadrant divs with material design? such as http://jsfiddle.net/CRSVU/ I know you can do row or column, can you combine them? Thanks!

Comment: `layout-wrap` is gonna help: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/225/). Just go through [layout documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) and see all the options. But if you want something called [grid list](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList) in matedial design, it's really good for setting ratio to the tiles or just their height. Here is [documentation for grid list](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList).

Comment: Or this [jsfiddle with column and row combination](https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/226/)